# Ping linux c++ сокеты

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, tcp-ip, unix-socket

Есть реализация пингования (для проверки наличия соединения между клиентом и сервером), прочёл несколько статей, видел разные реализации, остановился на этой. В общем если пинг норм, возвращается 0, а если нет, то 1.
У меня возвращается всегда 0, я пробовал разные хосты, реальные по типу google.com и локальный 127.0.0.1.
Проверял при наличии соединения с сервером и без, результат один и тот же...Не понимаю, что я делаю не так..Если что, всё запускается корректно с правами root, так что не нужно удивляться, почему необработанный (сырой) сокет создаётся.

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/param.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/file.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <netinet/in_systm.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netinet/ip.h>
    #include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #define PACKETSIZE  64
    struct packet
    {
        struct icmphdr hdr;
        char msg[PACKETSIZE-sizeof(struct icmphdr)];
    };
    
    int pid=-1;
    struct protoent *proto=NULL;
    int cnt=1;
    
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*--- checksum - standard 1s complement checksum                   ---*/
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len)
    {
        unsigned short *buf = (unsigned short*)b;
        unsigned int sum=0;
        unsigned short result;
    
        for ( sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2 )
            sum += *buf++;
        if ( len == 1 )
            sum += *(unsigned char*)buf;
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
        sum += (sum >> 16);
        result = ~sum;
        return result;
    }
    
    
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*--- ping - Create message and send it.                           ---*/
    /*    return 0 is ping Ok, return 1 is ping not OK.                ---*/
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    int ping(const char *adress)
    {
        const int val=255;
        int i, sd;
        struct packet pckt;
        struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
        int loop;
        struct hostent *hname;
        struct sockaddr_in addr_ping,*addr;
    
        pid = getpid();
        proto = getprotobyname("ICMP");
        hname = gethostbyname(adress);
        bzero(&addr_ping, sizeof(addr_ping));
        addr_ping.sin_family = hname->h_addrtype;
        addr_ping.sin_port = 0;
        addr_ping.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)hname->h_addr;
    
        addr = &addr_ping;
    
        sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP); // пробовал с PF_INET, результат тот же
        if ( sd < 0 )
        {
            perror("socket");
            return 1;
        }
        if ( setsockopt(sd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, &val, sizeof(val)) != 0)
        {
            perror("Set TTL option");
            return 1;
        }
        if ( fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) != 0 )
        {
            perror("Request nonblocking I/O");
            return 1;
        }
    
        for (loop=0;loop < 10; loop++)
        {
    
            socklen_t len=sizeof(r_addr);
    
            if ( recvfrom(sd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&r_addr, &len) > 0 )
            {
                return 0;
            }
    
            bzero(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));
            pckt.hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO;
            pckt.hdr.un.echo.id = pid;
            for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(pckt.msg)-1; i++ )
                pckt.msg[i] = i+'0';
            pckt.msg[i] = 0;
            pckt.hdr.un.echo.sequence = cnt++;
            pckt.hdr.checksum = checksum(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));
            if ( sendto(sd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)addr, sizeof(*addr)) <= 0 )
                perror("sendto");
    
            usleep(300000);
    
        }
    
        return 1;
    }
int main() {
  std::cout << ping("127.0.0.1") << std::endl;
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Я проверил поле msg в пакете при чтении функцией recvfrom, оно не совпадает со значением при отправке..Но так всегда, что есть подключение к серверу, что нет...

Comment: Удивительно, что сокет вообще создается. По идее для RAW сокетов требуется запуск от суперпользователя или соотв. привилегия.

Comment: Ну блин..очевидно, что я запускаю с правами root через sudo, раз не пишу, почему это вообще не работает)

Comment: Нет, это совершенно не очевидно. Кроме того, в приведенном фрагменте отсутствует подключение заголовочных файлов, а функция ping вообще не вызывается. Как всегда в подобных случаях, требуется [mcve]

Comment: Очень странно, что для Вас это не очевидно) Хорошо, сейчас добавлю полный код и пример использования в одну строчку

Comment: Я думаю, что надо анализировать получаемый пакет. У вас при, скажем, icmp ответе network unreachable тоже будет возвращаться 0.

Comment: Типа могут быть какие-то данные в любом случае, и уже нужно посмотреть их, чтоб понять, корректно ли работает соединение?

Comment: ICMP это datagram protocol (соединений нет), но в любом случае вас должны интересовать только пакеты в ответ на ваш запрос. Т.е. смотрите внимательно на ICMP ECHO протокол (например, https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml) / Кстати, если хотите, чтобы другой юзер получал notification, указывайте в комментарии `@его-ник`